# Are there any recent tools to help find org health?

Tags: pmd, usagemetrics

I am looking to get metrics using Apex PMD on the status of all metadata in our org. Are there any ways to compile all of this data or any other tools that will be able to compile this data and analyze the progress of the org health?

Comment: Are you looking for a free or paid solution? I have heard really good things about https://www.getclayton.com/

Comment: Ideally free/opensource

Comment: I would start here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-pmd-plugin/